# Objective-C static library with implementation source hidden

Tags: objective-c, static-libraries

I have written a static library in Objective-C that is to be shared with other projects. However, I want to distribute the library with just the header files available as source, not the implementation.

If this is possible, could you please describe the steps necessary?

At present I include the library in other apps by dragging the .xcodeproj file into the Xcode file tree of the consuming app. Would this approach also have to change?

Comment: do you know what a static library is?

Comment: `by dragging the .xcodeproj file` an .xcodeproj file is not a static library

Answer (score 0):

Try this reference (Creating a Static Library in iOS Tutorial from Ray Wenderlich's site): 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial